# How To Compare Values Between Two Different Sized Csv Files?

Tags: java, csv, while-loop

I was wondering what is the most appropriate way of looping through two csv files and comparing their columns. Specifically I want to compare the csv file1 1st column to every iteration of csv file2 column 20 and check to see if there is a match. Here is what i have so far. In addition csv file1 is considerably smaller than csv file2.

```
public class ClassifyData {

public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{

File file1 = new File("file1.csv");

File file2 = new File("file2.csv");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/Users/home/Work.csv");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(writer);
Scanner in = new Scanner(file1);
Scanner in2 = new Scanner(file2);
boolean firstLine = true;
String[] temp = null;
String [] temp2 = null;
String line = null;
String line2 = null;

while((line = in.nextLine())!=null){

    temp= line.split(",");  
while(line2 = in2.nextLine() !=null){
    temp2 = line2.split(",");


    if(temp[0] == temp[20]){
        System.out.println("match");
        pw.append("0");
        continue;

    }




    pw.append("\n");

    }
}

pw.flush();
pw.close();
writer.close();

}

    }
```

Comment: Well, go back to the questions you posted earlier, see which one the best answer is, and "accept" it - click on the tick mark below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your solution is going to work because you're going through both files just once (you're sequentially incrementing through both files simultaneously). Given that the first file is small, I suggest going through that file completely once, and store the values in the first column in a hashtable. Then cycle through the second file, and check if the value in the 20th column appears in the hashtable or not.

Comment: Thank you Ansari, though I found using an ArrayList of String best fitted for my efforts.

Comment: You're welcome, although I still suggest using a HashTable for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

In the line `if(temp[0] == temp[20])` you probably mean `if(temp[0].equals(temp2[20]))`. This will give you the comparison you want. However, you're inner `while` loop still won't start over at the beginning of the second file like you seem to want. I don't think `Scanner` objects  can start over on a file, and even if they could, you'd be wasting a lot of file reads by reading the same file over and over. Something like this will be more efficient for your disk:

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>;
while((line = in.nextLine())!=null){
    temp= line.split(",");  
    list1.add(temp[0]);
}
// ...
for(int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++){
        if(list1.get(i).equals(list2.get(j))){
            System.out.println("Match found");
        }
    }
}
```

**Warning:** *untested code*